# Embedding videos in Evernote notes?

Tags: video, images, embedded, evernote

Using the Evernote web clipper, I have the option to clip Youtube video pages.

[image]

This results in a note with an embedded video thumbnail, which when clicked opens the Youtube page:

[image]

How can I manually add a video to an Evernote note to have it show up in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Here is the answer from an Evernote developer: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-embed-a-video-in-Evernote/answer/Brett-Kelly:

> If you're a Premium user, you can store a video file in Evernote (provided it's 50mb or less), but there's currently no way to embed a playable video (a la YouTube or similar).

Comment: Sorry about that. It's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you'll have to manually do it:

1. Get a thumbnail to represent the video you want to link to.
2. Add it to your note.
3. Select the picture/thumbnail (left click).
4. Go to the Evernote menu at the top of the window and click **Format**.
5. Ten click **Hyperlink**.
6. Finally **Add** and paste there the link to open the video page.

Comment: That doesn't describe a process of embedding. That's just linking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that is worth considering

1. Right-click the YouTube video to get the embed code
2. Paste into a new notepad file and save as video.html
3. Drag this HTML file into your Evernote note
4. When you double click on the link it opens in a new tab, you don't get the message that you are leaving Evernote

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible with the revamped Evernote applications (on all platforms - web app included).
Just copy the YouTube URL, paste it in any note and press return. Evernote will automatically embed a playable video (probably an iframe) into your note.